# ClassCastException using ArgumentCapture for Double in scala

Tags: scala, mockito

I'm having a problem using `ArgumentCapture` for a `Double` in scala. I'm trying to capture a `Double` argument to a mocked trait. The same syntax works fine when trying to capture an `Int`.

Here's an example test:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor

trait MockedTrait {
    def mockedDoubleMethod(double: Double)
    def mockedIntegerMethod(integer: Int)
}

class ClassUnderTest(myTrait: MockedTrait) {
    def methodUnderTest {
        myTrait.mockedIntegerMethod(3)
        myTrait.mockedDoubleMethod(5.0)
    }
}

class MyTest extends FunSuite with MockitoSugar {

    test("A basic test") {
        val myTrait = mock[MockedTrait]

        val classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(myTrait)
        classUnderTest.methodUnderTest

        val capturedInteger = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[Int])
        verify(myTrait).mockedIntegerMethod(capturedInteger.capture)

        val capturedDouble = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[Double])
        verify(myTrait).mockedDoubleMethod(capturedDouble.capture) // Throws ClassCastException
    }

}
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(Unknown Source)
    at MyTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(MyTest.scala:30)
    at MyTest$$anonfun$1.apply(MyTest.scala:20)
    at MyTest$$anonfun$1.apply(MyTest.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuite$$anon$1.apply(FunSuite.scala:1265)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1968)
    at MyTest.withFixture(MyTest.scala:18)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. This should fix it I believe:

```
val capturedDouble = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[java.lang.Double])
```